# How to "link" a page, so that the navigation bar stays at top in bootstrap

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation

When I tried to create a link that would refer to a new website within my page I wondered how this is done right. I used the following code:

```
<li><a href="aktuelles.html">Aktuelles</a></li>
```

It's a simple link and when clicked, the page appears, but without the navigation bar at top.
My question is: Is there any other way to create a link (For example one frame at the top and one beneath it, and the at the top always shows the navbar) or do you always code the navigation on all subpages in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to store your navigation in one file, for example nav.html and include it in each file you have. In that way it will be present in all your pages and in the same time if you want to edit your navigation you just have to edit in one place and not in any file.